# Singelton Pattern Processing

Tags: java, processing

Hi i want to add a singelton pattern in processing

```
public class Singleton {

    private static final Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    private Singleton() {
    }

    static Singleton getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }

}
```

Error:
The field instance cannot be declared static; 
static fields can only be declared in static or top level types

Thanks Hans

Answer (score 1):

It seems your `Singleton` is an inner class. From the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3) :

> An inner class is a nested class that is not explicitly or implicitly declared static.
>
> Inner classes include local (§14.3), anonymous (§15.9.5) and non-static member classes (§8.5).
>
> Inner classes may not declare static initializers (§8.7) or member interfaces, or a compile-time error occurs.
>
> Inner classes may not declare static members, unless they are constant variables (§4.12.4), or a compile-time error occurs.

Specification say that inner class may declare only compile-time constant fields, and `private static final Singleton instance = new Singleton();` is not a **compile-time** constant.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a **new tab** and name it **Singleton.java**. Every class which uses static variables needs to be put in a java file when using the Processing IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

public class Singleton {
    private static final Singleton instance;

```
private Singleton() {}

 public static Singleton getInstance() 
 {
    if(instance != null)
      return instance;
    else
         {
            instance = new Singleton();
         }
 }
}
```

Comment: You could also just make the entire class a static class. Less effective but not by much. But the singleton pattern should look like above more or less. I am rusty with Java.

Comment: In the Processing IDE you cannot use static variables like this, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can't tell, a processing sketch is a single Java top-level class, no matter how many tabs you add. The tabs are just there to help you organize code, but they still belong to a single class. This class is called whatever your sketch is called and extends the PApplet class in processing's core. Any class you define in your sketch will be part of the top-level class (an inner class), and since the compiler won't let you set static inner classes, you can never actually create this.

In general, I don't understand why anyone would want to add the Singleton pattern in processing. The reasoning behind it is to not permit spawning objects from that class apart from the single one that is defined in the pattern. This behaviour is useful mostly when designing APIs, or when you have such big programs that you need to keep track of what spawns where. The singleton pattern is useful there because in a way, it restricts what each top-level class can do to another top-level class. Another reason behind the Singleton pattern is to allow for global fields and methods (which you can use in all your program). Since a processing sketch is essentially a single java class, you already have this functionality, and can just set the method or field anywhere in the program.

Those are things that you wouldn't do in processing, but probably in a full blown java environment that does not restrict you like that, such as eclipse. The idea behind processing is to make things as simple as possible, thus restricting you in various ways, and that's why I love it for a quick sketch! When your program becomes big / convoluted you are better off switching to another IDE.

If you want though, you can go ahead and provide us with the reasoning behind your selection of this pattern, and then someone can answer with the best possible way to do that!

Answer (score 0):

If your Singleton is an inner class, you should declare it static to be able to have static members in it

```
public static class Singleton {
   ...
```